# How to blur everything except one element

Tags: html, css

I wonder how can I blur everything except one element which have id `pad` I tried `body:not(#pad)` but `#pad` also blurs

```css
#foto img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 3px 1px rgba(63, 63, 63, 0.322);
}

#pad {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 50000000000;
  transform: scale(1.8) translate(30%, 30%);
  ;
  bottom: 50%;
}
body:not(#pad) {
  filter: blur(3px);
}
```

```html
<div id="foto">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534067783941-51c9c23ecefd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531804055935-76f44d7c3621?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjExMjU4fQ&w=1000&q=80">
  <img id="pad" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534067783941-51c9c23ecefd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80">
</div>
```

Comment: You have added blur property to .blur class. But there is no class as blur in the HTML code. Please update the correct code

Comment: This `body:not(#pad)` needs to be this `#foto :not(#pad)` - Note the space!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this way

```
img:not(#pad){
   filter: blur(3px);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/2qfncehy/3/

Comment: What if there are not only imgs and also other elements, for example there are other `p`s also how can I blur everything, In your case only images are blurred

Comment: you can use this way `#foto > *:not(#pad)
        {
            filter: blur(3px);
        }` https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/2qfncehy/10/

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by adding generic class to your photos. And then you can choose to ignore `#pad` with `:not`

```css
#foto img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 3px 1px rgba(63, 63, 63, 0.322);
}

#pad {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 50000000000;
  transform: scale(1.8) translate(30%, 30%);
  bottom: 50%;
}

.photos:not(#pad){ filter: blur(3px) }
```

```html
<div id="foto">
  <img class="photos" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534067783941-51c9c23ecefd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80">
  <img class="photos" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531804055935-76f44d7c3621?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjExMjU4fQ&w=1000&q=80">
  <img class="photos" id="pad" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534067783941-51c9c23ecefd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80">
</div>
```